# Dropbox filesListFolder says my path is invalid

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I'm using the Dropbox Javascript SDK to call `dropbox.filesListFolder({ path: 'apps/my_app' })` and Dropbox returns the 400 error

```js
Error in call to API function \"files/list_folder\": 
request body: path: 'apps/my_app' did not match pattern 
'(/(.|[\\r\\n])*)?|id:.*|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)'
```

I've checked that my app has the correct permissions, generated a token on the API website to test with, and checked the folder exists in my account in the Dropbox app.

I've also tried the paths `Apps/my_app`, `my_app`.

Using backslashes like `apps\my_app` or `apps\\my_app` or `apps\\\my_app`  doesn't work either.

What else can I try please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than for the root itself (which would be just the empty string `""`), Dropbox API paths should start with a "/". So for your example, you would supply `"/apps/my_app"`.

Also, note that if your app has the "app folder" [access type](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/developer-guide#app-permissions), your paths will automatically be interpreted relative to the app folder itself, so you wouldn't include the `"/apps/my_app"` portion. That is, in that case to list the root of the app folder itself, you would just supply `""`, or to list some folder, for example named "subfoldername" inside the app folder, you would supply `"/subfoldername"`.

Comment: Thank you! Also, do you know where I can find info on the difference between a token and a code? https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide just says: 'Your application exchanges the authorization code for an access token that can be used to make secure calls to the Dropbox API (not shown)" but I can't find an explanation anywhere

Comment: @Richard You can find [the documentation for the Dropbox authorization flow here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization). [This blog post](https://dropbox.tech/developers/using-oauth-2-0-with-offline-access) may also serve as a useful example.

Comment: But also why did it not just tell me 'path not found', instead of 'doesn't match our regex', which it does. Confusing API

Comment: @Richard I'm not sure I understand your comment. The regex is a way of identifying and enforcing the valid format for the path parameter, and your original `'apps/my_app'` does not match the `'(/(.|[\\r\\n])*)?|id:.*|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)'` regex, which starts with `'/'` for the path format (the first portion in the regex).